# TeeChart X axis labels shows same value when chart size became small

Tags: c#, wpf, teechart, axis-labels

I have a question with the axis label of teechart in WPF. When the labels is small and the reduce the width of the chart the number of the chart bottom axis labels' number will reduce too. but it shows same labels. I have tried change the label format but didn't work. Is there any way to prevent the same labels? Thanks for the help. 
The first chart is the chart before reduce the width. The second chart is the chart after reduce the width.

[image: This is the chart before reduce the width]

[image: This is the chart after reduce the width]

Comment: I'm not sure about which is your exact problem. Could you please add a code snippet or send a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/) so that we can reproduce the problem here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have a point series chart which x value is very small and the chart size will change when i change the wpf grid which hold the chart like chart.Width = (int)grid.RenderSize.Width;chart.Height = (int)grid.RenderSize.Height;  When the size is small the x axis ticks number will reduce and the value presented same.

Comment: Could you please illustrate that with an example we can run "as-is" to reproduce the problem here? Thanks.